# i want to build a bmi calculator and im totally new to programming

Tags: tkinter

im totally new to programming. can somebody checck if my code is correct. if so, can somebody tell me how to continue cuz im kinda stuck. heres the code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from functools import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x400")
root.title("bmi calculator")
label1 = tk.Label(root, text="please enter your weight in kg").pack()
label2 = tk.Label(root, text="please enter your height in metres").pack()
e1 = tk.Entry(root, height=2, width=30).place(x=30, y=90)
e2 = tk.Entry(root, height=2, width=30).place(x=50, y=90)


def calculationtool1(bmi1, bmi2, result1, result2):
bmi1 = (bmi1.get())
bmi2 = (bmi2.get())
result1 = int(bmi2)*int(bmi2)
result2 = bmi1/result1

bmi1 = StringVar()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x400")

msg1 = Label(root, text = "please enter your weight in kg").pack()
msg2 = Label(root, text = "please enter your height in metres").pack()

n1 = StringVar()
n2 = StringVar()

e1 = Entry(root, width = 15, textvariable = n1).pack()
e2 = Entry(root, width = 15, textvariable = n2).pack()



def submit():
    h = n1.get()
    w = n2.get()
    bmi = int(h) * int(w)
    print(bmi)
    

submit1 = Button(root, text = "Submit", command = submit).pack()

root.mainloop()
```